# Youtube Video playing with no audio in iOS 11 using youtube-ios-player-helper

Tags: swift4

I am trying to integrate Youtube video using [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)

This is playing youtube video with **videoId** properly with audio in iOS 9 (iPod).
But when I am trying to play in iOS 11 (iPhone 6) then it plays without audio.

Please help how can I resolve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @RazKarapetyan.

Import AVFoundation framework.
Then before playing video set audio session category to Playback as below code: -

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
} catch {
    // failed to record!
}
```

Its working for me.

Comment: Thank you! Works for me.

Comment: Hi @johnnelm9r, Please mark correct if works proper. So it can help others also.

Comment: I gave you an upvote. I’m not the original poster so I don’t think I can mark it as the correct answer. I wish I could tho.